Does Vagabond gain points when using Ambush card against hostile in Root
When Vagabond is hostile with another player and uses an ambush card against them, does Vagabond gain Infamy points?
Rule:

Infamy: Score one extra victory point for each piece of a Hostile faction you remove in battle during your turn, except the warrior that made the faction Hostile. (Add this to points scored for enemy buildings and tokens.)


No, the vagabond does not score victory points for infamy, since in order to score they need to remove hostile faction warriors in battle during the vagabond's turn. The ambush card normally does not allow to do that.
However if a vagrant uses their special "Instigate" action to make a hostile opponent attack them on vagrant's turn and play ambush during that battle, the vagabond will score victory points for infamy, if pieces are removed by ambush.
